# AVD is located over UNC path and cannot start

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

How does one tell it where to put the AVD?  by default it is creating it in my windows home directory under a .android folder.

i cannot start my avd if its located over a \unc path\to\avd.

our sys admins put all of your home directories on another shared server.

Thanks in advance,

Kirby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix.   ANDROID_SDK_HOME path variable set to teh mapped drive

Example...

My windows user's home drive is \servername\path\to\me ...  i mapped H: to \servername.

ANDROID_SDK_HOME = "H:"

Not intuitive in my opinion, but atleast there is any easy fix for anyone in the future who has their sys admins setting them up like this.

Also to tell your AVD where to be installed you can use the -p flag

android create avd -n my_android1.5 -t 2 -p path/to/my/avd

Cheers!